# Using math.random for A/B testing

Tags: javascript, jquery

Currently I have setup a piece of code to use for A/B testing based on 50/50. But now I want to rebuild it to a 50/25/25 setup. What is the best way to define the Math.random numbers?

```
// Launch A/B test surveys
if (/GB|CA|MY|EG|US|Global/i.test(_satellite.getVar("dlCountry")) && /EN/i.test(_satellite.getVar("dlLanguage"))) {
    if (!_satellite.readCookie("s_UbVar")) {
        // Make 50/50 split and set cookie
        var UbVariant = RegExp(/true/).test(String(Math.random() < 0.5));
        if (UbVariant) {
            _satellite.setCookie("s_UbVar", "varA");
        } else {
            _satellite.setCookie("s_UbVar", "varB");
        }
    } else {
        // Extend session cookie
        _satellite.setCookie("s_UbVar", _satellite.readCookie("s_UbVar"));
        if (_satellite.readCookie("s_UbVar") === "varA") {
            usabilla_live("trigger", "survey-A");
        } else if (_satellite.readCookie("s_UbVar") === "varB") {
            usabilla_live("trigger", "survey-B");
        } else {
            // Cookies contains an empty/unknown value
            _satellite.removeCookie("s_UbVar");
        }
    }
} else {
    // Remove existing cookies
    _satellite.removeCookie("s_UbVar");
}
```

Comment: `RegExp(/true/).test(String(Math.random() < 0.5));` -> I'm not sure that could have been made much more convoluted?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just setup your points like such

```
var variant = Math.random();
if (variant < 0.5) {
    // A Code
}
else if (variant > 0.75) {
    // B Code
}

else {
    // C Code
}
```

Comment: `if (variant < 0.75)`; because the upper border is never reached for random

Comment: wouldn't that have the same issue then? your suggestion is more logical though

Answer (score 0):

Or without if's:

```
const tt = Math.random()
switch (true) {
  case (tt<.5):
    // do 1
    break
  case (tt<.75):
    // do 2
    break
  default:
    // do 3
}
```